# MVC3 - Validating inputs - Difference between create() and edit()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm again struggling at validating inputs.
Let's say I edit a customer and the field "name" is required via

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ErrorMsgNameMissing)]
public string NAME { get; set; }
```

inside the model.

The edit method does

```
[HttpPost]
edit(ViewModel vm)
{
    // some code here    
    try
    {
        UpdateModel(vm);
        // some code there
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

While doing `UpdateModel(vm)`, an exception is thrown if the name is empty. Then my view shows the Html.ValidationSummary(). So far, so good.

Now, if I create a customer via

```
[HttpPost]
create(ViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
}
```

I don't have the method `UpdateModel()` since there's nothing to update. And `ModelState.IsValid` seems to return `true` every time. Even if the ViewModel is null. So I run into trouble then.

How do I validate this? And what do I return in case of errors?

**Update:** I think it was too late yesterday. In fact, it DOES work. But I was hoping for an exception and forgot the `else { ... }`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true)]
create(ViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I just tried, but it's the same result as before. Doesn't work. Does ModelStae.IsValid work like UpdateModel with reflection?